# ReferenceError: function is not defined error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wish to call the setValue function when an emit event has been fired and the `$on` listener is run.
I am getting the following error: `ReferenceError: setValue is not defined`
Why is this happening?

```
angular.module('clientApp')
.service('ManagerService',
['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

  var someValue = false;

  this.setValue = function(value) {
    someValue = value;
  }

  $rootScope.$on('event', function(event, data) {
    setValue(true);
  });

}]);
```

Comment: "How can I fix this?" Define `setValue` variable or declare a function with this name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `setValue` variable or declare a function with this name.

```
angular.module('clientApp')
.service('ManagerService',
['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

  var someValue = false;

  this.setValue = setValue;

  function setValue(value) {
    someValue = value;
  }

  $rootScope.$on('event', function(event, data) {
    setValue(true);
  });

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

store **this** object into variable and then use it

```
angular.module('clientApp')
.service('ManagerService',
['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
var vm = this;
  var someValue = false;

  vm.setValue = function(value) {
    someValue = value;
  }

  $rootScope.$on('event', function(event, data) {
    vm.setValue(true);
  });

}]);
```